# How does a transformer derive query, key, and value weights from the input embedding?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I confused myself when looking at the transformer model diagram, since there are three arrows that go into a multi-head attention block.  I understand these arrows to represent the query, key, and value matrices, but I'm slightly confused as to how the single line that represents the input embedding suddenly forks into Q, K, V.

My impression was multi-head attention derives Q, K, V after having received the input.  Therefore, I'm not entirely sure why, in the transformer diagram, the input splits into Q, K, V *before* it reaches a multi-head attention block.

Is this representation for visual/intuitive purposes, or is my understanding of multi-head attention wrong?

Thanks for the help!